# where the working class lived or live?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Which one is more correct:

> It was for a long time a poor neighborhood where the working class **lived**.

Or:

> It was for a long time a poor neighborhood where the working class **live**.

Thanks

Comment: Neither is more correct. Which verb form you choose depends on what you want to say and on whether the working class still live there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends, what are you trying to say?

They lived or they continue living there?

1. If they continue living there then you must to express through the second one
2. If they already not living there then choose the first one